# How do I add windows phone system colors to icon using expression design?

Tags: windows-phone-7, icons, expression

I am trying to create icons in Microsoft Expression Design, but I want to add the system resource colors like the phone background and foreground so that the icons change color when the user changes the theme.  Does anyone know how to specify the windows phone system colors in Expression Design, or how to import them?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a great blog post that I've used before which goes step-by-step into applying the System themes into images (which should be white.. but It'll get into the nitty-gritty details!)

[Using an image as a mask so that WP7 theme’s are honoured](http://advertboy.wordpress.com/2010/09/25/using-an-image-as-a-mask-so-that-wp7-themes-are-honoured/)

For example, here's how you can do it using a Rectangle and OpacityMask:

```
<Rectangle Fill="Black" Height="48" Width="48">
            <Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="/MyProject;component/Images/Dark/appbar.add.rest.png" />
            </Rectangle.OpacityMask>
        </Rectangle>
```

Note that the `Height` & `Width` are set explicitly to the `Width` & `Height` of my `ImageSource`. This fixes the stretching issue that will occur if you don't do this.

Comment: Thanks! This was along the lines of what I was looking to do.  One problem I encountered was theres a black border that cuts off part of the image.  I have to enlarge the whole button to fix, but then the image is too big.  Any ideas how to get around this?  (alhtough I may use a rectangle instead of button since I'm only making a prototype.  I can convert he rectangle into a navigation control after.

Comment: @erotavlas I've updated my answer with a sample of how I use it in my application (although not with the Color 'Black', obviously)