# Replace white in an image with accent colour

Tags: image, windows-phone-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how do I add windows phone system colors to icon using expression design?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11199751/how-do-i-add-windows-phone-system-colors-to-icon-using-expression-design)

I'd like to know whether there's any way I could take a PNG file (white and transparent) and replace the white in it with the accent (or some other) colour?

Many thanks in advance!

Can

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I answered this exact question two days ago:

This is a great blog post that I've used before which goes step-by-step into applying the System themes into images (which should be white.. but It'll get into the nitty-gritty details!)

[Using an image as a mask so that WP7 theme’s are honoured](http://advertboy.wordpress.com/2010/09/25/using-an-image-as-a-mask-so-that-wp7-themes-are-honoured/)

For example, here's how you can do it using a Rectangle and OpacityMask:

```
<Rectangle Fill="Black" Height="48" Width="48">
            <Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="/MyProject;comåponent/Images/Dark/appbar.add.rest.png" />
            </Rectangle.OpacityMask>
        </Rectangle>
```

Note that the `Height` & `Width` are set explicitly to the `Width` & `Height` of my `ImageSource`. This fixes the stretching issue that will occur if you don't do this.